# C++ tokeniser, skip the lines start with '//' and the ad hoc '/**/'

Tags: c++

I am practising to write a tokeniser in C++, however, I assume that I will need to take a file with some comments as the input file. Then how can I skip the comments like those in the following picture.
Any ideas?[image]

Comment: At first I tried a way like, read the first token char, if it is a '/', keep reading the next char till the end of line. But it only worked for the first line.

Comment: Would you accept sed-based solutions? Or if you insist awk, perl, etc?

Comment: You want us to write code?

Comment: Please give additional information by editing your question.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right @EdHeal. Hello OP Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour,  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you tried a way, please post the code in the body of your question. You can edit it at any time to add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

for `//` with `regex` library you can:

```
// for "//"
for( std::string line; std::getline( input_file_stream, line ); ){
    if( std::regex_search( line, std::regex( R"(^//)" ) ) ){
            // nothing
    }
    else {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

Also for other part `/**/` you can use `regex` again
but without `regex` you can:

```
std::ifstream input_file_stream( "file" );

// for // and /* up to */
for( std::string line; std::getline( input_file_stream, line ); ){
    if( *line.begin() == '/' ){
        if( *(line.begin() + 1) == '*' ){
            while( *line.begin() != '*' && *(line.begin() + 1 ) != '/' ){
                std::getline( input_file_stream, line );
            }
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}

input_file_stream.close();
```

**test, input:**

```
// skip
// skip
okay
// skip
okay
okay
/* skip up to
not
not
not
*/
okay
the end
```

**and the output:**

```
okay
okay
okay
okay
the end
```